# Understanding the physical interpretation of the third virial coefficient's peak and zero-crossing point

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential-energy, ideal-gas

In the figure posted below (source: [doi.org/10.1021/ie00077a027](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie00077a027)), the third virial coefficient of water shows some interesting features: it crosses the origin around 590K and exhibits a peak at approximately 670K.
[image: Image of third virial coefficient taken from DOI: 10.1021/ie00077a027]

Questions:

1. Physical Interpretation: What is the physical significance of both the peak and the zero-crossing point in the third virial coefficient curve? My intuition is that the zero-crossing corresponds to a point where the attractive intermolecular interactions are (in a sense) balanced by repulsive interactions due to thermal motions. Is this correct?
2. Impact of Different Potentials: How would these features change under different conditions? If one were to increase the dipole moment of a molecule, would the third virial coefficient cross zero and reach its peak at lower or higher temperatures? What would be the effect on the third virial coefficient if the size of the molecule increases?

I'm particularly interested in an intuitive understanding of the peak and zero-crossing phenomena in the third virial coefficient curve. Any explanatory material or references on this subject would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: I have seen explanations for the second virial coefficient, but never the third. The temperature where the second virial coefficient is zero is known as the Boyle temperature.